# MinHeap Insertion of Element Having Same Priority

Tags: c++, data-structures, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to implement MinHeap. I have implemented by writing the following insertion code:

```
 int i = 0; //<declaring variable for "for loop"

//<Check if MinHeap is full
if (current_size == capacity - 1)
    expand();

current_size++; //<increase current size

for (i = current_size; true;)
{
    if (i == 1)
        break;

    if (key > array[i / 2])
        break;

    array[i] = array[i / 2];

    i /= 2;
}

array[i] = key;
```

Deletion Code:

```
int i = 0, j = 0; //<declaring variables for "for loops"

if (current_size == 0)
    return nullptr;

key = array[i]; //<array is started from index 1

type k = array[current_size--];

for (i = 1, j = 2; j <= current_size;)
{
    if (j < current_size)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            j++;
    }

    if (k >= array[j])
        break;

    array[i] = array[j];

    i = j;
    j *= 2;
}

array[i] = k;

return &key;
```

I'm trying to modify it so that it can add elements with equal priority correctly.

Whenever I insert 4, 5, 4 in the same sequence the last element(4) is stored at index 3 of the array. I do understand that its not Binary Search Tree and the array still has heap structure but whenever I delete the top most element(4) at index 0 the top most element becomes 5 instead of the last 4. Should I change insertion algorithm or deletion algorithm?

Thanks :)

Edited: After doing more tests, using different ways, I have found that the problem is in deletion code. For example: If I insert 4, 5, 6, 4 and print them the order is right: 4, 4, 5, 6. So I think the problem is with the deletion code but I followed the algorithm correctly(or I hope so :). Can anyone kindly point out the problem in the deletion code?

Thanks

Comment: and the question is..?

Comment: Exactly where you are having problem in implementation?

Comment: @Shan Added more info.

Comment: You specified that inserting 4, 5, 6, 4 behaves correctly. Which scenario behaves incorrectly? To make your question clearer, please provide an example code that reproduces the problem, [MCVE](http://s.tk/mcve).

Comment: @MCVE thank you for replying. I have cleared the question 2 hours ago already (Have labeled it "Edited:" too). I have answered the question. Again thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found the answer. There was a problem with the deletion code.

int i = 1, j = 2; //

```
if (current_size == 0)
    return nullptr;

key = array[1]; //<array is started from index 1

type k = array[current_size--];

for (i = 1, j = 2; j <= current_size;)
{
    if (j < current_size)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            j++;
    }

    if (k < array[j])
        break;

    array[i] = array[j];

    i = j;
    j *= 2;
}

array[i] = k;

return &key;
```